# Creating an (Intervals) Frequency Table Histogram

Tags: r, histogram, gsub

I have the following frequency table of intervals:

| Height (inches) | Class Mark | Frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0–10 | 5 | 5 |
| 10–20 | 15 | 18 |
| 20–30 | 25 | 12 |
| 30–40 | 35 | 6 |
| 40–50 | 45 | 9 |

For which I tried to create a histogram using the following `R` code:

```
# Example data frame for a continuous frequency table
df <- data.frame(
  ClassInterval = c("[0, 10)", "[10, 20)", "[20, 30)", "[30, 40)", "[40, 50)"),
  Frequency = c(5, 8, 12, 6, 9)
)

# Extract numeric values from class intervals
class_intervals <- gsub("\\[|\\)|\\(|\\]", "", df$ClassInterval)
class_midpoints <- sapply(strsplit(class_intervals, ","), function(x) mean(as.numeric(x)))

# Manually specify breaks based on unique values in ClassInterval
breaks <- as.numeric(gsub("\\[|\\)|\\(|\\]", "", unique(df$ClassInterval)))

# Create a histogram
hist(class_midpoints, breaks = breaks, weights = df$Frequency, col = "skyblue", xlab = "Value", main = "Continuous Frequency Histogram")
```

However, the command that creates `breaks` seems to generate only `NAs`, and consequently the `hist` gives me this error:

```
Error in hist.default(class_midpoints, breaks = breaks, weights = df$Frequency,  : 
  negative length vectors are not allowed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In min(h[h > 0]) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? And how to fix the problem? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What is your desired output of `breaks` ? At the moment, your `gsub` will return a character vector with each element having two numbers separated by a comma (ie, `"0, 10"`) - if you wrap this in `as.numeric("0, 10")` it will return `NA`. In this example, do you want `c(0, 10)`?

Comment: As @jpsmith already mentioned, your desird output is unclear. Do you want `with(df, barplot(height = Frequency, names.arg = ClassInterval))`?

Comment: @jpsmith `breaks` should specify that the bars should cover the intervals: first bar covers 0-10, the second bar covers 10-20, and so on.

Comment: @Friede your command is good, but I would like to use the `hist` function instead of `barplot`.

Comment: You already have the counts, `hist` is not appropriate for your problem.

Comment: *Friede your command is good, but I would like to use the hist function instead of barplot.* As @RuiBarradas wrote, this does not make any sense. I think my above suggested approach is what you can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your toy data, we can create a **bar plot** where we display the weighted frequencies against the point ranges ("Class Intervals"):

```r
df <- data.frame(
  ClassInterval = c("[0, 10)", "[10, 20)", "[20, 30)", "[30, 40)", "[40, 50)"),
  Frequency = c(5, 8, 12, 6, 9)
)

with(df, barplot(height = Frequency / sum(Frequency), names.arg = ClassInterval, 
                 ylab = "Frequency", xlab = "Class Interval"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>